# Size problem while making .Pst file manually

Tags: outlook-redemption, pst

I am creating a .pst file manually by opening it in the outlook and add/copying its own folders containing mail items , just to exceed its size.
But after adding and exceeding its size and closing it from the outlook and close the Outlook itself, it was showing the same size as it has earlier.

For example: 
i have " 1 GB " of pst file , i want to exceed its size to " 4 GB "by opening it in outlook and copying its own folder data or folder into itself.
but it was failed and showing same size i.e 1 GB after closing it from the outlook.

I just want to know why the file size not exceeded ? 
if anyone of you tried this earlier, let me know.

Comment: That means the PST file data is not gracefully flushed and the PST file closed. Keep in mind that PST provider keeps the file loaded for another 30 minutes (or until Outlook terminates) and does not flush the data immediately. Is the file modified using Redemption? Or by manually copying the items from another store?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko,  No the file is not modified by redemption and also the items are not copied from another store . its the same store and i am copying its folders and items in it multiple times to make it 4 GB

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, can you elaborate this "That means the PST file data is not gracefully flushed and the PST file closed" , what should i acutally need do ? , We have to save that store or anything else.

Comment: You just need to make sure Outlook is gracefully closed.